# Imprimir reportes con React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navegador-web, ecmascript

Buenos días, soy prácticamente nuevo con esta tecnología y bueno estoy haciendo mis pinitos. Estoy con un proyecto para mi empresa y me gustaría saber si hay posibilidad de imprimir ciertos informes directamente a impresora mediante react.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo máximo que puedes hacer es pedirle al navegador que abra la ventana de impresión para el usuario con

```
window.print();
```

Con lo que se imprimirá el documento que tengas abierto en esa ventana/pestaña.

Y para que se vea bonito, puedes definir CSS específicamente para la impresora. No tiene que verse lo mismo en el papel que en la pantalla si no lo deseas (puedes esconder imágenes, quitar colores para ahorrar tinta, cambiar el ancho para que no tenga que escalar...) mediante el uso de

```
@media print {
  /*css aquí */
  body {
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Pablo por la rápida respuesta. Supongo que el contentido de dicho reporte es que le paso en el componente en si, ¿cierto? Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve que hacer algo similar mira mi aporte para que te guies:
https://github.com/MangelDark/GenerationPDF

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/320575)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).